# Prime zeta function and squarefree divisors

Tags: number-theory

Let $x_n$ and $y_n$ be two random numbers, drawn uniformly and independently from $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Write $d_{\text{sf}}(x_n,y_n)$ for the number of squarefree divisors of $\gcd(x_n,y_n)$. We are interested in the expected value of $d_{\text{sf}}(x_n,y_n)$ as a function of $n$, as $n$ increases.

**Claim.** With the notation as above, the expected value of $d_{\text{sf}}(x_n,y_n)$ relates to the prime zeta function in that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} E\big(d_{\text{sf}}(x_n,y_n)\big) = \sum_{p\text{ prime}} \frac{1}{p^2}.$$

Does anyone know of a proof of this?

Comment: Perhaps I'm thinking too difficult. Fix a prime $p$, and consider the $n^2$ combinations of pairs $(x_n,y_n)$. Then there's a probability $1 / p^2$ that both elements $x_n$ and $y_n$ divide $p$... That allows you to see reciprocals of primes squared. Maybe this helps?

Answer (score 2):

Your claim is incorect. I will give two answers with different perspectives
**Solution 1**

Let's tweak your claim. There you miss two facts, the first one is that every combination gives a factors $(1)$ and that a prime adds another one, so a good lower bound based on your clain is
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}E[d_{sf}(X_n,Y_n)]\geq1+\sum_{p\text{ prime}}\frac1{p^2}\approx1.4522474200\dots$$
We'll see that the real value is $1.5198177546\dots$ , which is a $4.4\%$ error.
The other fact is that more primes add more square-free divisors, in fact, it doubles for each prime added, so the correct series would be
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}E[d_{sf}(X_n,Y_n)]=1+\sum_{p\text{ prime}}\frac1{p^2}+\sum_{p_1,p_2\text{ primes}}\frac{a_2}{p_1^2p_2^2}+\cdots+\sum_{p_1,\dots,p_m\text{ primes}}\frac{a_m}{p_1^2\cdots p_m^2}+\cdots$$
Using $a_0=1,a_1=1$, we must have that $2^m=\sum_{i=0}^m{m\choose i}a_i$, as it's the sum of all square-free divisors on the left side plus all the terms that add to it on the right side.
From this, it's easy to see that $a_i=1$ is the solution, as it follows from the sum of binomial coefficients. Then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}E[d_{sf}(X_n,Y_n)]=1+\sum_{p\text{ prime}}\frac1{p^2}+\sum_{p_1,p_2\text{ primes}}\frac{1}{p_1^2p_2^2}+\cdots+\sum_{p_1,\dots,p_m\text{ primes}}\frac{1}{p_1^2\cdots p_m^2}+\cdots=$$
$$=\prod_{p\text{ prime}}\left(1+\frac1{p^2}\right)=\prod_{p\text{ prime}}\frac{1-p^{-4}}{1-p^{-2}}=\frac{\zeta(2)}{\zeta(4)}=\frac{\frac{\pi^2}{6}}{\frac{\pi^4}{90}}=\frac{15}{\pi^2}\approx1.5198177546\dots$$
Where the jump from the first line to the second is the distributive property.

**Solution 2**

An easier solution from the ground up is the following. We have that the probability for each number is $P(X_n=m)=1/n$, then the probability of any number $m$ dividing $X_n$ is
$$P(m\mid X_n)=\sum_{\substack{i=1\\m\mid i}}^n\frac1n=\frac{\left\lfloor\frac nm\right\rfloor}{n}=\frac{\frac nm-k}{n}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{n}{m}}{n}=\frac1m\qquad k\in[0,1)$$
Where $k$ comes from the definition of the floor function.

On the other hand, it's conditioned probability with $\gcd(a,b)=1$ is
$$P([b\mid X_n]\mid[a\mid X_n])=\sum_{\substack{i=1\\b\mid i}}^{\left\lfloor\frac na\right\rfloor}\frac{1}{\left\lfloor\frac na\right\rfloor}=\frac{\left\lfloor\frac {\left\lfloor\frac na\right\rfloor}b\right\rfloor}{\left\lfloor\frac na\right\rfloor}=\frac{\left\lfloor\frac{\frac na-k_1}b\right\rfloor}{\frac na-k_1}=\frac{\frac{n}{ab}-k_2}{\frac na-k_1}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{n}{ab}}{\frac na}=\frac1b\qquad k_1,k_2\in[0,1)$$
So they are independent at $n\to\infty$

Now let's calculate the limit. As we said before, the number of square-free divisors of the gcd is multiplied by two for every prime in its factorization, due to the fact that the prime is or isn't in the divisor, and having it more than once is a contradiction with it being square-free. Let m be the number of primes in the gcd. Then in the limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}E[d_{sf}(X_n,Y_n)]=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\prod_{\substack{i=1\\p_i\text{ prime}}}^m\frac{2}{p_i^2}\prod_{\substack{p\text{ prime}\\p\neq p_i\ \forall\ i}}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right)=$$
$$=\prod_{p\text{ prime}}\left(1+\frac1{p^2}\right)=\frac{15}{\pi^2}$$
Where the jump from the first line to the second is the distributive property. It's easy to see that in the summation and products, we consider all posible square-free divisors, ordered with the number of primes the have.

In the general case, if we consider $l$ independent variables
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}E[d_{sf}(X_{n,1},...,X_{n,l})]=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\prod_{\substack{i=1\\p_i\text{ prime}}}^l\frac{2}{p_i^l}\prod_{\substack{p\text{ prime}\\p\neq p_i\ \forall\ i}}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^l}\right)=$$
$$=\prod_{p\text{ prime}}\left(1+\frac1{p^l}\right)=\prod_{p\text{ prime}}\frac{1-p^{-2l}}{1-p^{-l}}=\frac{\zeta(l)}{\zeta(2l)}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac1{n^2}\sum_{a\le n,b\le n}\omega(\gcd(a,b))=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{p\le n} \sum_{a\le n,b\le n, p| a,p| b}1$$ $$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac1{n^2}\sum_{p\le n}  \lfloor n/p\rfloor^2=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac1{n^2}\sum_{p\le n}  (( n/p)^2+O(n/p))$$ $$= \lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{p\le n} p^{-2}+O(\frac1n \sum_{k\le n} k^{-1})=\sum_p p^{-2}$$

Comment: What are omega and O?

Comment: $\omega$ is the number of prime divisors and $O$ is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation essential for asymptotic calculations.

Comment: I know I'm a bit late, but this does not appear to be correct. Clearly, the limit must be greater than $1,$ since every integer has at least one squarefree divisor (namely $1$). $P(2)\approx 0.4522<1.$ The premise of the question itself is incorrect I think.

Answer (score 1):

Your claim is wrong. The correct solution is the following:

**Claim**
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} E[d_{sf}(x_n, y_n)] = \prod_{p \text{ prime}} \left(1 + \frac{1}{p^2}\right) = \prod_{p \text{ prime}} \frac{\frac{1}{\left(1 - \frac{1}{p^2}\right)}}{\frac{1}{\left(1 - \frac{1}{p^4}\right)}} = \frac{\zeta(2)}{\zeta(4)} = \frac{\frac{\pi^2}{6}}{\frac{\pi^4}{90}} = \frac{15}{\pi^2}
$$

**Proof**

Firstly, we proof that
$$
E[d_{sf}(x_n, y_n)] \leq \prod_{p < n, p \text{ prime}} \left(1 + \frac{1}{p^2}\right)
$$
To do that, consider the following inequality
$$
\prod_{p < n, p \text{ prime}} \left(1 + \frac{1}{p^2}\right) \geq \sum_{q < n, q\text{ squarefree}} \frac{1}{q^2}
$$
because if we expand every product, we arrive at a sum of the square inverses of square free numbers whose prime factors are less than n.

Now, let $n = kq + r$, where $r < s$. Notice that
$$
k^2 = \sum_{x_n, y_n, q|x_n, q|y_n} 1 \leq \left( \frac{n}{q} \right)^2
$$

Finally, putting all together

$$
\prod_{p < n, p \text{ prime}} \left(1 + \frac{1}{p^2}\right) \geq \frac{\sum_{q < n, q\text{ squarefree}} \sum_{x_n, y_n, q|x_n, q|y_n} 1}{n^2} = E[d_{sf}(x_n, y_n)]
$$

Thus

$$
E[d_{sf}(x_n, y_n)] \leq \prod_{p < n, p \text{ prime}} \left(1 + \frac{1}{p^2}\right) \leq \prod_{p, p \text{ prime}} \left(1 + \frac{1}{p^2}\right)
$$

On the other hand, let's show that
$$
E[d_{sf}(x_n, y_n)] \geq \prod_{p < m, p \text{ prime}} \left(1 + \frac{1}{p^2}\right) - \epsilon
$$
for $n$ great enough. Let
$$
P = \prod_{p < m, p \text{ prime}} p
$$
Let $n = kP + R$. Then
$$
n^2 E[d_{sf}(x_n, y_n)] \geq (kP)^2 E[d_{sf}(x_{kP}, y_{kP})] \geq (kP)^2 \prod_{p < m, p \text{ prime}} \left(1 + \frac{1}{p^2}\right)
$$
where the first inequality holds because it is the total number of square-free divisors of any pair, and the second one because
\begin{gather*}
\prod_{p < m, p \text{ prime}} \left(1 + \frac{1}{p^2}\right) = \sum_{q\text{ squarefree}, p|q \rightarrow p < m} \frac{1}{q^2} = \sum_{q\text{ squarefree}, p|q \rightarrow p < m} \frac{ \sum_{x_n, y_n, q|x_n, q|y_n} 1 }{(kP)^2} \\
\leq E[d_{sf}(x_{kP}, y_{kP})]
\end{gather*}
Finally
$$
((k+1)P)^2 E[d_{sf}(x_n, y_n)] \geq n^2 E[d_{sf}(x_n, y_n)] \geq n^2 E[d_{sf}(x_n, y_n)] \geq (kP)^2 \prod_{p < m, p \text{ prime}} \left(1 + \frac{1}{p^2}\right)
$$
Finally
$$
E[d_{sf}(x_n, y_n)]  \geq \frac{k^2}{(k+1)^2} \prod_{p < m, p \text{ prime}} \left(1 + \frac{1}{p^2}\right)
$$
Choosing $m$ big enough, $n$ big enough
$$
E[d_{sf}(x_n, y_n)] \geq \prod_{p, p \text{ prime}} \left(1 + \frac{1}{p^2}\right) - \epsilon$$
$\square$

In general, if we have $l > 1$ variables, the limit exists and is
$$
\frac{\zeta(l)}{\zeta(2l)}
$$