# Limit of expected number of squarefree divisiors of gcd as n approaches infinity

Tags: number-theory, expected-value, gcd-and-lcm, prime-factorization

Let $X_n$ and $Y_n$ be two random numbers, drawn uniformly and independently from {1,…,n}. Find $\lim _ {n \rightarrow \infty}$ of the expected value of the number of squarefree divisors of gcd($X_n, Y_n)$.

I found that the squarefree conditions means that the number of squarefree divisiors is $a ^k$ where $a$ is the amount of prime divisors. I'm a bit stuck though now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prime zeta function and squarefree divisors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3995219/prime-zeta-function-and-squarefree-divisors)

Comment: I don't understand that solution (I'm not very good at maths yet). I was looking for if there was an easier solution. But thanks for linking that question.